# How to access SharePoint Online APIs from App, not user auth

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad

I am looking to grant an application access to write to our SharePoint Online lists. We have Azure AD setup as an option. I don't want to prompt users for authentication/access, I want the app to get a token and then access SPO.

I got as far as creating the AAD App registration, and I can get the token from there, but I can't get into SharePoint. The App reg has Permissions to SPO

[image]

But my gut is that I need to allow this access in my site collection, and that's where everything goes dark. No idea where/how to do that. If I'm even on the right path.

**UPDATE**

I tried going down the Graph path, but to read/write list items is in Beta, and even that wasn't working, see other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554169/access-sharepoint-sites-lists-via-microsoft-graph

Comment: have you looked at provider hosted apps with app-only token ?

Comment: I haven't, this is a headless service accessing SP, doesn't fit the traditional app model.

Answer (score 1):

To access your SharePoint online site from any APP using preferred technology Microsoft Graph is the best way to do that.

Microsoft Graph exposes multiple APIs from Office 365 and other Microsoft cloud services through a single endpoint:  https://graph.microsoft.com.

You can read below article to understand and get started.

[Overview of Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs)

[Get Started with Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start)

[Working with SharePoint sites in Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/sharepoint)

Comment: Right, but the app will be writing to the list as well, my understanding the Graph doesn't support that side of it.

Comment: Here is an article explains the operations you can do on a list item. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/listitem

Comment: How does an app gain access now? Graph is very user-centric but I want generic application access to write to a list. Combing through documentation and samples....

Comment: As per docs my understanding is to read and write resource on behalf of user you can get an access token. More details here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user

Comment: This requires the user to log in and authorize, unless I'm missing something

Comment: HOWEVER the page below your linked page appears to be what I need. Chasing this down, https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Comment: The link one I have to execute something in the app on behalf user. The second one you are referring is to update where apps run on a server without a user present. I thought in App means you need to run on behalf of a user. However, you got the way to read.

Comment: This doesn't seem like its going to work, the list API is only avail on Beta and I can't even get that to work, need prod-ready functionality

Answer (score 0):

To write item sharepoint list your app should have below permission

Permission type Permissions- (from least to most privileged)
Delegated (work or school account)  -Sites.Manage.All
Application-    Sites.ReadWrite.All

Post URl: POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists

POST /sites/{site-id}/lists
Content-Type: application/json

```
{   "name": "customer list",   "columns": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "text": { }
    },
    {
      "name": "address",
      "text": { }
    }   ],   "list": {
    "template": "genericList"   } }
```